# how to get a key name of a sub key from array

Tags: php, arrays

hello I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    ["foobar"] => Array
        (
            [00] => Array
                (
                    [ACC] => off
                    [engine] => 1
                    [lat] => 31.451825
                    [long] => 74.287766666667
                    [speed] => 0.3704
                    [timestamp] => 2018-05-13 00:00:33
                )

            [01] => Array
                (
                    [ACC] => off
                    [engine] => 1
                    [lat] => 31.451848333333
                    [long] => 74.287743333333
                    [speed] => 0.07408
                    [timestamp] => 2018-05-13 00:01:32
                )
```

I get a key like this `echo key($array);`. This will give me the key name which is `foobar`. Now I want to get a key which is under this key `foobar` which is `[00]`. how can I get just this key `[00]` and `[01]` which is under `foobar`

Comment: `array_keys($array['foobar']);`

Comment: `key(reset($array))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all keys in a certain array - use `array_keys`:

```
$keys = array_keys($array['foobar']);
// second key is:
echo $keys[1];
// value under this key is:
var_dump($array['foobar'][$keys[1]]);
```